# add Extensions library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I develop an application under eclipse, but there is some library in the folder "Extensions" of java (`libopencv_java.so`), how can I do to add it in eclipse?
under eclipse in java build path, I can add just jar files :/

Comment: In the _Java Build Path_ dialog select the _Native library location_ sub-node of the added JAR, click _Edit..._ and specify the folder containing the `*.so` files.

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Please describe the problem so that it can be reproduced. It's unclear what you have right now and what you mean by _"it doesn't work"_ (no error message?). How to successfully start the application from the command line?

Comment: The project that uses this library (works fine) but when I export it as a jar file and integrate it into another project it does not work

Comment: I export the project as `runnable jar`, so when I launch it by double-click the library doesn't work, but when I launch jar with `java -jar myapp.jar` It works, and in my project I load it by `<jar href="myapp.jar" main="true"/>` and doesn't work

Comment: `java -jar myapp.jar`
log : 
`at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path: [/Users/username/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
 at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
 at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
 ... 5 more`

Comment: The error message says that `opencv_java.so` is missing. The file `opencv_java.so` is not found in any of the directories listed in `[` ... `]` (`.` means the current/working directory). Please note, native libraries (`*.so` files) referenced via `java.library.path` cannot be placed inside a JAR.